# I try to generate output the json string return from php but i cant do it

Tags: json

tthe following is my json string return from php and suggest me how i can get value from following json string.

```
[
    {
        "picid": "13",
        "itemcode": "P-0000001",
        "filename": "-1970-01-011.jpg",
        "primarystatus": "active"
    },
    {
        "picid": "16",
        "itemcode": "P-0000001",
        "filename": "dateArray1.jpg",
        "primarystatus": "active"
    },
    {
        "picid": "18",
        "itemcode": "P-0000001",
        "filename": "dateArray3.jpg",
        "primarystatus": "active"
    },
    {
        "picid": "19",
        "itemcode": "P-0000001",
        "filename": "dateArray4.jpg",
        "primarystatus": "active"
    }
]
 //php
  function returnALLPic()
 {
    if(isset($_POST['id']))
    {
        $data= $this->m_phone->getAllPictureInformation($_POST["id"]);


    $ss= json_encode($data);
    echo $ss; 
    }

 }
```

//jquery
$.ajax({

```
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'http://localhost/tt/index.php/ad_access/c_r/returnALLPic',
           data: 'id='+ei,
           success: function(msg)
           {
```

// console.log(JSONObject);      // Dump all data of the Object in the console

```
             $('#model').html(msg[0].itemcode)

           }


           });
```

Comment: Where is your code? I see only a JSON string

Comment: What language are you using? Which value are you trying to get?

Comment: It's an array of object. create a class containing above 4 properties.

Comment: Have a look at the following post + answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995877/get-value-from-json-array-in-php

Comment: Use $arr = json_decode($json);

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json using following code.

```
var json = $.parseJSON(j);
$(json).each(function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(k,v){
          console.log(k+" : "+ v);     
});
});
```

Comment: I do not know how to get value parse from php .i try by seeing other example including u and i cant do it.I am new to json.However Thank u for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you need to output in php, use `json_decode()`

then get what you want from the loop

`$sss= json_decode($data)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in PHP as well.

Read this using

```
$data = file_get_contents('Your_URL')
```

and then use following function to parse it

$phpArray =  json_decode($data);

You can do what ever you want do with that