# Decode multidimensional array and insert into mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I have trouble with getting a value from an xmlhttp request after sending it with ajax to a php file and insert it into an mysql database. I get from the yahoo finance api the output you can see in the html snippet. After that the value of this html element should be sended to the file `insertvolume.php`.

After successful sending I save the data into an variable named `$jsonString` and decode it. Then I try to insert a specific value from the array into my mysql database but it wont work. I think the problem is that the value is into any other arrays but I dont know how to write that. I only need that array named  `results` Any hints?

**the html:**

```
   <div id="output">{"query{"count":1,"created":"20160215T09:15:04Z","lang":"deDE","resu‌​lts":{"quote":{"symbol":"ZN","Ask":"2.05","LastTradeRealtimeWithTime":null,"Chang‌​ePercentRealime":null,"ChangeFromYearHigh":"-0.45","LastTradeWithTime":"4:00pm<b>‌​1.81</b>",astTradePriceOnly":"1.81", "Volume":"500","HighLimit":null,"LowLimit":null,"DaysRange":‌​"1.781"}}}}</div>
```

**javascript:**

```
var outputt = $('#output').text();
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "insertvolume.php",
            data: {myData: outputt},
            success: function(data){
                //alert('Items added');
            }
    });
```

**some pice of code from insertvolume php:**

```
 $jsonString = $_POST['mydata'];
    $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$jsonArray1 = $jsonArray['query']['results']['quote'];
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO volume ( stocksymbol, volume, time) VALUES ( ?, ?, now())')) {

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        $stmt->bind_param($jsonArray1['symbol'], $jsonArray1['volume']);

        /* execute query */
        $stmt->execute();

        /* close statement */
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Comment: I can't tell if that JSON is not valid, or it got messed up when you pasted it in. As is, there are line breaks in it though.

Comment: I made these line breaks for better reading but I can delete them.

Comment: Is your html ouput is like this : 
`<div id="output">{"query{"count":1,"created":"20160215T09:15:04Z","lang":"deDE","results":{"quote":{"symbol":"ZN","Ask":"2.05","LastTradeRealtimeWithTime":null,"ChangePercentRealime":null,"ChangeFromYearHigh":"-0.45","LastTradeWithTime":"4:00pm<b>1.81</b>",astTradePriceOnly":"1.81","HighLimit":null,"LowLimit":null,"DaysRange":"1.781}}}}</div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After decoding the data you cannot retrive the json data directly. We should create object for that. Here i am giving you the reference link of how to access values of json.

[Get value from JSON array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995877/get-value-from-json-array-in-php)

Comment: Can I decode it like that: ´$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);´ and the into mysql instad of ´$jsonArray1['volume']´ this: ´$query->results[0]->{"quote"}->Volume´? I dont understand the rules/ syntax when select the specific value of this:´$query->results[0]->{"quote"}->Volume´ is it right like that?

Answer (score 1):

In javascript code it is written as 
var outputt = $( "#output" ).val();

But the div is not having the value. The content is present inside the div. So change the line code to

var outputt = document.getElementById('output').textContent and try.

Now you are able to access the array in javascript. But we are unable to access the data of output code from your line.

Comment: Oh thank you I didnt know that div's havent a value property, but it didnt change sth on the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

In ajax call remove the line

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

and then execute. It will work

Comment: I delete the line but nothing happens.