# How to echo special value from key in array/json structure

Tags: php, arrays, json, list

I can easly explore json for example:

```
foreach($json_a['somwhere'][1]['somwhere_deeper'] as $something){
    var_dump($something);
}
```

This code makes me print something like this:

```
C:\wamp64\www\dothejob.php:7:
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'John' (length=17)
  'value' => string '15' (length=4)
C:\wamp64\www\dothejob.php:7:
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Joanna' (length=6)
  'value' => string '23' (length=2)
C:\wamp64\www\dothejob.php:7:
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'John' (length=17)
  'value' => string '55' (length=10)
C:\wamp64\www\dothejob.php:7:
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Joanna' (length=11)
  'value' => string '55' (length=5)
```

So I'm sure I'm in a right place, but now the question is how to print only value which is in array, where name is Joanna?

I know it should be easy If statement, but I'm not sure how those keys/values works, Its easy question, but I'm beginner with php... :) ps. I was looking for help but didn't found solution yet.

Can't use $something[n], because they are not allways on the same "place", so only right solution is something like this:

I'm looking for something like this:

```
if 'name' is 'Joanna':
print value of 'value'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from JSON array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995877/get-value-from-json-array-in-php)

Comment: And many mooooooooore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$something[n]` because you have an associative array :

```
foreach($json_a['somwhere'][1]['somwhere_deeper'] as $something){
    if ($something['name'] == 'Joanna') {
        var_dump($something);
    }
}
```

Output should be :

```
C:\wamp64\www\dothejob.php:7:
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Joanna' (length=6)
  'value' => string '23' (length=2)
C:\wamp64\www\dothejob.php:7:
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'Joanna' (length=11)
  'value' => string '55' (length=5)
```

Of course, if you want to `var_dump` the value only, use `var_dump($something['value'])`.

Comment: But I want to have an output look like 
23
55 only

Comment: Then use `echo $something['value']`, it will output `2355`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks mate, your great! I'll accept answer asap :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to update naming convension of Variable

```
foreach($json_a['somwhere'][1]['somwhere_deeper'] as $key => $value){
    echo $key." : ".$value
}
```

Output of above code will be something like
John : 15
Johnna : 23

```
foreach(array as key => value)
{
 //key represent array key
//value represent value of that array
}
```

Let me know in case of any concern.