# PHP check JSON string for item = value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to get the value one one particular value in my json string

the json string comes from an api url `http://url:port/api.php?action=reg_user&sub=list` and outputs like so

```
[{"id":"1","username":"username1","credits":"0","group_id":"1","group_name":"Administrators","last_login":"1511883014","date_registered":"1421604973","email":"test1@my-email.com","ip":"8.8.8.8","status":"1"},{"id":"31","username":"username2","credits":"0","group_id":"1","group_name":"Administrators","last_login":"1539813642","date_registered":"1473632400","email":"test2@my-email.com","ip":"8.8.8.8","status":"1"},
```

i would like to check the value of credits where username = username1

then if credits > 30 do x, else do y

I presume first of all I need to decode this jason string

so i tried to do

```
$api_result = file_get_contents( 'http://url:port/api.php?action=reg_user&sub=list' );
$json_decode = json_decode($api_result);
echo $json_decode;
```

expecting this to echo the array in a nicely formatted structure, instead it just outputs the word `Array`. Where do I go from here?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1...**

SO i checked again and I defo can echo $api_result so I know that the `file_get_contents` is working fine i tried the two comments suggestions however both didn't work...

one of the suggestions was to make my php
    $api_result = file_get_contents( 'http://url:port/api.php?action=reg_user&sub=list' );
    $json_decode = json_decode($api_result);
    echo $json_decode['username'];

here is a screenshot of how the echo $api_result is formatted in case this isnt a propper json string

[image: edit 1 - echo of $api_result]

so to me this looks like it opens with (and is all contained in a pair of [] and then each result is enclosed in {} as I'd expect with a json string right? however i thought json strings used {} and arrays used {} so to me this looks like a string inside an array???

I looked at [php.net's resource on JSON DECODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)  and tried `var_dump(json_decode($json));` which did print me this

[image]

UPDATE 2

I just tried https://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html and pasted the data in, it was able to decode the data absolutely fine,

It then gave me a copy if the json_decode sample at the bottom but this didn't work either, returning a null value like json_decode doesn't work on my server?

Comment: If it **is** indeed an array, what you need to do is access it as you would access an array. E.g., `echo $json_decode['username']`. If you want to see the whole array at once, create a loop for it, or just dump the variable using `var_dump`

Comment: Use `print_r(json_decode($api_result));` to pretty print a structure. Run a loop over the decoded structure and check `$arr[i]['credits'] > 30`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read and print json array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277289/read-and-print-json-array-in-php)

Comment: thanks for your comment @Wreigh however unfortunately this echo'ed nothing. returned a blank screen

Comment: update your question to include what you've tried so we can help you further :)

Comment: thanks @Wreigh i have done... Please note the secion about it being formatted as [{string}] inside of square brackets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your second screenshot (please cut & paste the text instead!) you can see the decoded JSON is an array of objects with properties `id`, `username` etc. So you can access them using object notation. This code uses the snippet of your api_result from your original question to demonstrate how to do what you want:

```
$api_result = '[{"id":"1","username":"username1","credits":"0","group_id":"1","group_name":"Administrators","last_login":"1511883014","date_registered":"1421604973","email":"test1@my-email.com","ip":"8.8.8.8","status":"1"},{"id":"31","username":"username2","credits":"0","group_id":"1","group_name":"Administrators","last_login":"1539813642","date_registered":"1473632400","email":"test2@my-email.com","ip":"8.8.8.8","status":"1"}]';
$json = json_decode($api_result);
foreach ($json as $user) {
    if ($user->username == 'username1') {
        if ($user->credits > 30) {
            // do x
            echo "user $user->username has more than 30 credits ($user->credits)";
        }
        else {
             // do y
            echo "user $user->username has less than or equal to 30 credits ($user->credits)";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
user username1 has less than or equal to 30 credits (0)
```

Comment: this works perfectly until I try and make $api_result = my original file_get_contents

so is the issue I am having with my file_get_contents perhaps ??? could this be a character encoding issue?

Comment: comes back completely blank screen... presumably this is because it cant decode the info returned by the api...

Comment: sorry @Nick, my mistake I had made when typing back in the API URL... All sorted now this is perfect thank you !!!